# Parser generator, predicate not returing true or false

Tags: prolog, parser-generator

I have a some problem with my PROLOG assignment.

Namely, I have to write predicate accept(+Automaton, +Word) that return true if Word belong to language (Automaton is represented by Goto table, Action table and grammar, but it is not so important), false otherwise (it is required in my assignment to return true or false). I have written

```
accept(Automaton, Word) :-         
    parse(Automaton, Word, RightmostDeriv),
    nl, print_list(RightmostDeriv), nl.
```

where

Predicate `parse(+Automaton, +Word, -RightmostDeriv)` calculate righmost derivation. If Word cannot be parsed then `RighmostDeriv == ['mistake']`

As you see I can print rigthmost derivation, but I do not know how to return false or true.

I have found this https://csc.cdf.toronto.edu/mybb/showthread.php?tid=2100 and I see that here can be a problem.

But maybe is here any solution (e.g with member predicate, something like member('mistake', RightmostDeriv) ) to return true or false?

Edit: having

```
accept(Automaton, Word) :-         
    parse(Automaton, Word, RightmostDeriv),
    nl, print(RightmostDeriv), nl.
```

I received (Test 2 - example from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Additional_Example_1.2B1)

```
[4]  ?- make.

=============== Test 1  =================== 

[mistake]

=============== Test 2  =================== 

[5,3,5,2]
true .

[4]  ?-
```

and having:

```
accept(Automaton, Word) :-         
    parse(Automaton, Word, RightmostDeriv),
    RightmostDeriv \= ['mistake'].
```

I received (infinite loop)

```
?- make.

=============== Test 1  =================== 
^CAction (h for help) ? break
% Break level 1
[1]  ?-
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you'd have to add `RighmostDeriv \= ['mistake']` to check whether the word was accepted or not, yielding true or false as a result of the query.

Comment: hmm.. it does not help.I have enclosed in the edited part of question result of query.

Comment: If it does not end the problem is that you are leaving choicepoints somewhere, allowing the prolog engine to backtrack indefinitely. Looking at your example linked from wikipedia you can see that the first two rules may loop forever...

Comment: Most interesting parsing problems are about deterministic parsing, so there are plenty of points at which backtracking doesn't make sense. Just add some `cut` clauses to your parser, and it should be fine.